# What if I have the requirements for an outspoken badge but I don't have an account on the site?

Tags: discussion, badges

Let's say I have all the requirements to get an outspoken badge because I got 10 starred messages from 10 different users in a room that is connected to a site. What if I don't have an account on the site the room is connected to, how is the badge rewarded will it happen after creating the account (Maybe instantly or after a little while.), or do I have to make sure to create the account first to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you qualify for the badge in chat, then the only thing stopping you from earning it is the lack of a profile on that site. So once you have the profile, you'll be awarded the badge.